# Is the expression $\operatorname{int}(A^c) \subset\operatorname{int}(A)^c$ right?

Tags: general-topology

I´m looking for an answer to this implication.

Given a subset $A$ in a topological space $(X,\mathcal{F})$. Is the expression $$\operatorname{int}(A^c) \subset \operatorname{int}(A)^c$$ true, being $\operatorname{int}()$ the interior of $A$ and $A^c$ the complementary set of $A$?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $\mathrm{int}(U)$ is always a subset of $U$ by definition.  Since $\mathrm{int}(A) \subseteq A$, you have $X-A \subseteq X-\mathrm{int}(A)$.  But now we have
$$
\mathrm{int}(X-A) \subseteq X-A \subseteq X-\mathrm{int}(A).
$$

Comment: So simple, great! Thanks!! :)